# Python, Selenium - Can not find element inside IFRAME even after switching

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I am trying to get the value form an input field that is in an iframe. I switched to the iframe but the program is still unable to find the element, so a time out exception is raised. I am using the internet explorer web driver and I can not use any other driver because the website only works in internet explorer.

The code I use:

```
browser = webdriver.Ie()
browser.get('http://www.thewebsite.com')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'Content')))
MRR = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//INPUT[@id='txtTotalMonthlyCharge']"))).get_attribute('value')
```

I already tried increasing the wait time and also locationg by ID

The HTML:

```
<iframe id="Content">
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body style="margin-left: 0; margin-top: 0; overflow:hidden">
        <form name="frmServicesTree" method="post" action="ServicesTree.aspx?AccountNo=50084779&amp;pageID=SERVICESTREE" id="frmServicesTree">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="flowLabel" width="140px"><span id="txtTotalMonthlyChargelabel" style="width:95%;height:17px;">Total Monthly Charge</span></td><td class="flowReadOnly"><input name="txtTotalMonthlyCharge" id="txtTotalMonthlyCharge" type="text" readonly="" tabindex="-1" value="JA$11,199.00" style="vertical-align:top;width:100%;" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
    </body>
</iframe>
```

Comment: possibly a case issue?  Have you tried "//input..."?

Comment: In your code sample you are switching to the `iframe` by ID but the `iframe` in the HTML sample you posted has no ID. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Christine it has an idea. I just accidentally left it out in the example, my bad

Comment: Have you checked to see if that IFRAME is nested?